# How do I track tag badge progress for a given tag?

Tags: support, badges, profile-page, tag-badges

In the past I remember being able to choose on my profile page to track a tag badge progress. Now the gear button does not provide access to tag badges, or I cannot find them.

How do I track tag badge progress for a given tag?

Comment: They are in the left most box, although the UX is a tag unintuitive below 20K rep. See the full details on MSE: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/254052/cant-track-tag-badges-without-20k-rep

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can see your badge progress ...clicking right most symbol on this [**Image**](http://puu.sh/mBio6/d522e929c5.png)

and its in your **profile**

and about your tags this [**Link**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/284111/zespri?tab=tags) for your profile. little hack ;) .

> above tag **link** will work for **zespri** only

To track your next badge or any badge refer this image below[image]

Right most button is to choose next badge or any badge tracking.. see image below
[image]

and using leftmost button symbol you can choose a badge to track see below image
[image]

Comment: So there are two cogs on this profile page it turned out. I used the right one, and you are supposed to use the left as per Mureinik's link. If you can add this info to your answer, it will become perfect! =) Thanks!

Comment: @zespri see my edit for detailed explaination ...

Comment: Is there a way to track a gold badge for a particular tag?